# Where to subscribe to events of the inner object?

Tags: c#, oop, events

I'm often encountering a situation where I must decide where to subscribe to events of the inner object?

For example, I have an object model looks like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent1;
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent2;
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent3;
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent4;
}

class ClassB
{
    private ClassA a;
    public ClassA A 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.a;
        }
    }

    public ClassB()
    {
        this.a = new ClassA();
        // here subscribe to some events (for example, SomeEvent1 and SomeEvent2)
        // this.a.SomeEvent1 += OnSomeEvent1Raised;
        // this.a.SomeEvent2 += OnSomeEvent2Raised;
    }
}

class ClassC
{
    public ClassB B { get; }
}

class ClassD
{
    public ClassC C { get; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Here subscribe to another ones events of object C.B.A. For example:
        C.B.A.SomeEvent3 += OnSomeEvent3Raised;
        C.B.A.SomeEvent4 += OnSomeEvent4Raised;
    }

    private void OnSomeEvent4Raised(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnSomeEvent3Raised(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've tried to create something like a UML diagram:
[image]

Structure of existing code of my project has places where such object model exist (its has a places where subscribing to events implemented as in the example above - C.B.A.SomeEvent+= ).
I don't like it and want to change it. 
I want to here from you the best practices about this situation.

Alternative approach is to duplicate all events of classA in the classB, classC, classD. 
And then replace all subscriptions to events to **ONE PLACE** (I mean that in the classB we will subscribe/unsubscribe to all events of the object of ClassA. In the classC we will subscribe/unsubscribe to all events of the object of classB. And so on...) In this case all subscriptions and unsubscriptions will be in one place. Hope, you understand what I mean here.

Again, please rely on your knowledge and experience tell we how to resolve this situation.

**UPDATE**

Do you agree with me that subscriptions and unsubscriptions to events must be placed in ONE PLACE ?
Please, answer on this additional question too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't yo create a `puplic static class` that holds on to your event handlers. If these event handlers are specific to the particular classes, then use and interface and generics to facilitate generic handlers for all classes...

Comment: @Killercamless because I have a lot of classes like classA in the example above.

Comment: do you have any specific reasons of not using inheritance?

Comment: @daryal It's different classes and they don't have a common functionality. For example, I have class Student and this class have a property to class University. Do you think I need use inheritance here?

Comment: then you need to identify why in a class having university as a property needs to register events of students... In most cases, where I encounter this problem; I start to feel code has a bad smell.

Comment: @daryal, maybe my example wasn't be enough clear. I agree with you that code smells and it's a reason why I have posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in an [event aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

What it basically does is decoupling the publishers from subscribers - it's kind of a event container. You could get the event aggregator through dependency injection (e.g. MEF) for each class you'd like to subscribe or publish from.

The way I personally use and like it the most, is the way Rob Eisenberg implemented the event aggregator in Caliburn Micro:

- [NuGet Gallery](http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator)
- [Caliburn.Micro Event Aggregator Documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator)

In your case object A, B and C would share the same instance of an event aggregator, which means as soon as events are published on this event aggregator, all these objects recognize it. Class A, B and C are able behave differently, caused by different handling of certain events.

**EDIT**

The use of an event aggregator is, that you subscribe to the aggregator itself with an *instance of a class*. The connection between publisher and subscriber class happens through relying to the same instance of the event aggregator. In case of Caliburn.Micro subscription to certain events happens through implementing a generic interface (`IHandle<>`).
For example: if you'd like to subscribe to `MyCustomEvent` you implement the `IHandle<MyCustomEvent>` interface in the class to be subscribed.
This requires an implementation of the `void Handle(MyCustomEvent e)` method from the `IHandle<MyCustomEvent>` interface for this type of event. This method gets called everytime a (new) `MyCustomEvent` is published on the shared event aggregator.

Comment: What about where to place a subscriptions and unsubscriptions to events? Do you agree with me that we should do it in ONE PLACE?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think it the most precisely answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is way too much `public` stuff in your example. Hope I'll make sense below:

1. ClassB contains an object of type ClassA, and handles some ClassA events
2. ClassC contains an object of type ClassB but events are ignored.
3. ClassD contains an object of type ClassC *and handles events from the ClassA object inside the ClassB object contains in this ClassC objects*

#2 and #3 are not good: ClassC should handle *and implement* the events, handling them and letting them "bubble up" (invoking their own, same, event) for ClassD to handle correctly.

Basically, *all of them* should handle *all events*, either reacting to them (as in ClassB to ClassA's events) or just propagating them.

Comment: Your answer is the same as my alternative approach. And I agree with you. But in this case we will have a lot of "wrapped events" (Events from ClassA must be wrapped in the ClassB (added similar events). And so on..) I think this is why this approach also isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

Find nice solution here:

[Csharp-NotificationCenter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/438582/Csharp-NotificationCenter)

Comment: you should always try to add the essentials of a link in your answer, in case the link becomes bad or unavailable or what not. Then you can use the link as a reference