# C# notificationsCenter

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

I am looking for a solution In C# very similar  to the notifications Center that ios have built-in in the objective-c. I need to send messages between object like in the Notifications Center. do someone know a open-source that do that?

Comment: A Google search for [C# notification center] returned several promising results, including http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/438582/Csharp-NotificationCenter.

Comment: You also might be interested in my answer postet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479471/where-to-subscribe-to-events-of-the-inner-object/14480001#14480001)

Comment: You know what else is amazing. That article linked to by @JimMischel on CodeProject is written by a guy named "One Man Crew". What are the chances that someone on CodeProject would have written the EXACT thing you're asking about. And have the *same* handle! Small world...hmmm...