# Await events from child objects/viewmodels

Tags: c#, mvvm, async-await, mvvmcross

I'm building a WinRT/WP8 app using MVVM Cross, and one of the requirements is for the user to be able to upload images. As far as the main application is concerned, a "picture" is just a byte array with some meta-data - where it actually came from is none of it's business. What I have then (so far for WinRT, haven't implemented phone at all yet) is a "IPictureSource" interface, with a GetBytes method, and 2 implementations - LivePicture  and FileSystem. Each does what it needs to do to take/find an image, and returns it in the required format.

The app is a bit clunky at the moment, as the UI layer is sniffing device capabilities, and only allowing filesystem if a camera isn't available

What I want to do is abstract these a bit, possibly have two child viewmodels, one dedicated to the camera (that enables itself if available) and one for the filesystem, or maybe even a collection, if the device has more than one camera, to give the user the maximum choice.

Either way, I want to have a design whereby I have multiple sources for a picture, that are all capable of returning the appropriate data.

In the old days, I would expose a "PictureTaken" event on IPictureSource, and cycle through the child objects from the parent, register each event and process them through a common handler.

I can't see why that wouldn't still work, but as I've got a bit of breathing room to make the most of the new technologies (particularly async/await) is there now a better way of doing that, particularly one I could unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to get rid of these event handlers, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479471/where-to-subscribe-to-events-of-the-inner-object/14480001#14480001) here. Perhaps your MVVM framework provides already an event aggregator.

Comment: hmm, so the Observer pattern again then, obviously, tonight performing as the Event Aggregator. Thanks, I think MVVM Cross has a Messenger class, but I've not seen it in action. Having a look now ...

Comment: yep - that's how to do it. There's a PCL compliant messenger class in MVVM Cross. I do seem to be getting multiple subscriptions on the same viewmodel (that's been reloaded a few times). I suspect a Singleton is going to be needed now somewhere, but I'm definitely going in the right direction now. Thanks

Comment: Do you use a composer like MEF? That may occur that you subscript to the aggregator from the VM's constructor. I always got this, when I wanted to reuse a VM, but it got instantiated everytime I just wanted to *reactivate* it. Regarding MEF, the solution was to put the part creation policy attribute like this: `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]`. Instead of setting it to `CreationPolicy.NonShared`.

Comment: hey - not sure that's actually going to be a problem in the real application, I just threw some code together to see if it worked in principle. I had one VM which subscribed to a message in its constructor, and another VM which published. I went back and forth a few times, so a new callback was added each time to the messagehub. When the message was published, it went to all the subscribers, ie the callbacks defined each time the HomeVM was created. But this isn't the real way I'll be using it in the actual app, it'll be messaging from an unknown number of child VMs to a parent ...

Comment: I think the most important part is, that you need to differ between these two cases: **1.** If you walk back and forth between two different VM's/views, but the state of them is kept, it means, that you *reactivate* them. So you need to get the instance you created already on the *first* visit of this VM/view. **2.** If you really like to create new ones, you also instantiate them everytime you walk back or forth.
If you instantiate them everytime you actually want to *reactivate* it, you create a huge amout of VM's. And causes a lot of event catching, dependent on how long the app ran.